# unhashable type: 'OrderedDict'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, ordereddictionary

I am encountering an issue in Django when I try to do a PUT request in Postman.

I suspect the issue is because I have nested serializers in my model class, but I am not sure.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    foo_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    foo_statistics = models.ManyToManyField(TrainStatistics)

class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    blah_statistics = BlahStatisticsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('foo_statistics')
        depth = 2 

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `Summary` instance, given the validated data.
        """

        blah_statistics_data = validated_data.pop('blah_statistics')
        foo = Foo(**validated_data)

        for blah_statistic in blah_statistics_data:
            FooStatistic.objects.create(summary=summary, **train_statistic)
        return summary

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `Foo` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.blah_statistics = validated_data.get('blah_statistics', instance.blah_statistics) # This line is causing problems
```

Any idea what could be  causing this issue?

Comment: get to the bottom and post the trace where the error occurs in your code.

Comment: Never copy or link an image for the error, paste the full traceback.

Comment: Updated the question with the line that is causing problems at the bottom

Comment: @MatthewLin can you post the value of validated_data before the error ? I think the problem is that train_statistics is a ordered dict and ordered dicts are not hasheables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the validated data turns `train_statistics` into a `OrderedDict`(always it's a bit tricky working with nested serializers), so `OrderedDicts` are unhashable, so when you try to "`.get`" it raises an error.

An option is to set your field  `train_statistics`  into read only.

Then in your `update()` method, instead of using `validated_data` to get `train_statistics`,  use `request.data` for getting them. Do the same for `create()` method.

```
class SummarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    train_statistics = TrainStatisticsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Summary
        fields = ('train_statistics')
        depth = 2 

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `Summary` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        request = self.context['request']
        train_statistics_data = request.data.get('train_statistics')
        summary = Summary.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for train_statistic in train_statistics_data:
            TrainStatistics.objects.create(summary=summary, **train_statistic)
        return summary

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `Summary` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        request = self.context['request']
        instance.train_statistics =request.data.get('train_statistics', instance.train_statistics) # This line is causing problems
```

When you call your serializer, you need to pass request object as context data.

```
SummarySerializer(instance, data=data, context={'request':request})
```

or

```
SummarySerializer(data=data, context={'request':request})
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I added in your changes and it is saying that my 'SummarySerializer' object has no attribute 'request' in the update method. Would I have to pass this in as a parameter in the update method?

Comment: @MatthewLin Sorry, I forgot it, you need to pass it, I updated my answer.

Comment: In this case you're committing train_statistics data without validating it. Doesn't seem like the safest work around.